# how can I implement a XYLine jfreechart in java

Tags: java, hibernate, graph, jfreechart

I am new to jfreechart.I want to display a chart based on values from my data base table
Table is dns_time with fileds dns_lookup_time,update_time.
I want update_time on x-axis and dns_lookup_time on y-axis.And the curve should be displayed according to the values from the database.I am using hibernate and postgresql.Can any one help me how to achieve this.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look at [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html), which can detect a time series based on metadata. As noted in the API, "The first column will be the x-axis and remaining columns y-axis values."  Click on the class name to see the corresponding source, for [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html).

Addendum: If you don't want to use `JDBCXYDataset` directly with a JDBC query, it may be a useful outline of how to extend `AbstractXYDataset` to create a dataset based on a corresponding JPA query.

```
class JpaXYDtaset extends AbstractXYDataset {
    // implement required methods using JPA query results
}
```

Comment: can I use JDBCXYDataset with hibernate.I am using hibernate framework.Can I use JDBCXYDataset?

Comment: Yes, but you may want to also use it as a guide to writing your own notional `JpaXYDataset`.

Comment: what is JPAXYDataset?Is it different from JDBCXYDataset?Which one should i use?

Comment: If you don't want to use `JDBCXYDataset` directly with a JDBC query, `JpaXYDataset` is what you would write to accommodate your JPA query.

Comment: if i type JpaXYDataset in google it is not showing me result.From where can I get API for this JpaXYDataset.Please help me

Comment: I don't know of a concrete implementation of such a dataset; more above.