# JFreechart view specific data

Tags: java, sql, jfreechart

Today I just start to learn JFreeChart only and this is my code`

```
try{
       String query = "Select Purchase_Date,Total_Quantity_Purchased "
               + "from Purchases";



       JDBCCategoryDataset dataset = new JDBCCategoryDataset(javaconnect.ConnecrDb(),query);
       JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Chart", "Purchase Date", "Total Purchase", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
       BarRenderer renderer = null;
       CategoryPlot plot = null;
       renderer = new BarRenderer();
       ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Title",chart);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setSize(500,650);
   }catch(Exception ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(),"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
```

and my result is listing out all of my database's data.

And now I want to improve it , I want to search total purchase on specific date 
Example from july 1 to july 10 . Is there anyway to do this?? I am new to this. Please help. TQ

Edit :

```
java.util.Date utilStartDate = from.getDate();
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());     

java.util.Date utilStartDate2 = to.getDate();
java.sql.Date sqlStartDate2 = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate2.getTime());

String query = "Select Purchase_Date, Total_Purchase_Quantity from Purchasing Where Purchase_Date between "+sqlStartDate+" and "+sqlStartDate2+"";

JDBCXYDataset dataset = new JDBCXYDataset (javaconnect.ConnecrDb(),query);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Query chart", "Date", "Total Order", dataset, true,true,false);
BarRenderer renderer = null;
CategoryPlot plot = null;
renderer = new BarRenderer();
ChartFrame frame = new ChartFrame("Query Chart",chart);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(500,650);
```

Error give me not enough valid columns where generate by query

Comment: Add a suitable `WHERE` clause to your query?

Comment: String query = "Select Purchase_Date,Total_Quantity_Purchased "
               + "from Purchases Where Purchase_Date between "+date1+"and "+date2+"";

u mean this??

Answer (score 1):

Since your query looks at quantity for a range of dates, you might want to consider `JDBCXYDataset`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959102/230513), "which can detect a time series based on metadata;" use it with a time series chart, `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()`.

Addendum; *It give me error:* "Not enough valid columns [were] generated by query." *What does it mean?*

It's hard to say without a [complete example & schema](http://sscce.org/), but you can check your query against the [recognized](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html#line.249) `java.sql.Types`.

Comment: String query = "Select Purchase_Date, Total_Quantity_Purchased from Order1 Where Purchase_Date between "+sqlStartDate+" and "+sqlEndDate+"";

JDBCXYDataset dataset = new JDBCXYDataset (javaconnect.ConnecrDb(),query);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Query chart", "Date", "Total Order", dataset, false, true, true);

It give me error ( not enough valid columns where generate by query? 
What does it mean? Sorry I'm new to JFreeChart?

Comment: It looks look like `Purchase_Date` or `Total_Purchase_Quantity` are not one of the expected `Types`.

Comment: what are the mean " not one of the expected types" ?

Comment: As noted above, one of the [recognized](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html#line.249) `java.sql.Types`.