# Issue generating JFreeChart graph in Eclipse

Tags: java, performance, swing, jfreechart

I want to generate graphs using data from MySQL. I have tried the JFreeChart library, but it's not working in my project. I want to know which library can generate graphs better than JFreeChart, but also how to modify my JFreeChart code to work better than it does now. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
String query="select Entropy,TimeStamp from entropy where profile='Bandwidth in of all interface' order by walkinggroup";
ConnectDB conn=new ConnectDB("ip","root","124563");
JDBCCategoryDataset dataset=new JDBCCategoryDataset(conn.getConnection(),query);
JFreeChart chart=ChartFactory.createLineChart("entropy", "TimeStamp", "Entropy", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
BarRenderer renderer=null;
CategoryPlot plot=null;
renderer=new BarRenderer();
ChartFrame frame=new ChartFrame("Query chart",chart);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
```

---

[image: // graph now] /

[image: // database table]

Comment: For anyone to help you troubleshoot your code - you need to actually post it first ;-) Along with a brief explanation of what you expected to happen instead. As far the "better libraries", that is a subjective question, which is not really [on-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: i have post my code done ! plz help me tanks

Comment: Re edit: Why `JDBCCategoryDataset`? `JDBCXYDataset` will recognize the timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

I like [`JDBCXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCXYDataset.html), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959102/230513), for this. Absent a complete example, it looks like you've defeated the default auto ranging feature on the range axis, perhaps by invoking `setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true)`. The effect is to minimize the already small variability in your entropy values.

As for alternatives, see also FAQ [*13. Are there other "open source" chart libraries?*](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/faq.html#FAQ13).