# I need to create a XYLineChart with values from database (Java(Mysql)

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I need to create a `XYLineChart` with values from database.

I see this:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    XYSeries                series1   = new XYSeries("Lions");
                            series1.add(20, 10);
                            series1.add(40, 20);
                            series1.add(70, 50);

    XYSeries                series2   = new XYSeries("Rabbits");
                            series2.add(20, 30);
                            series2.add(40, 40);
                            series2.add(70, 10);

    XYSeriesCollection      xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
                            xyDataset.addSeries(series1);
                            xyDataset.addSeries(series2);

    JFreeChart              chart     = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Weight","kg","Numbers",xyDataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,false,false);
                            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.yellow); 

    XYPlot                  plot      = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
                            plot.setBackgroundPaint       (Color.white);
                            plot.setDomainGridlinePaint   (Color.GREEN);
                            plot.setRangeGridlinePaint    (Color.orange);
                            plot.setAxisOffset            (new RectangleInsets(50, 0, 20, 5));
                            plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
                            plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible (true);

    XYLineAndShapeRenderer  renderer  = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();      
                            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
                            renderer.setBaseShapesFilled (true);

    ChartFrame              frame     = new ChartFrame("ChartFrame", chart);
                            frame.setSize   (450, 250);
                            frame.setVisible(true);                   
  }  

}
```

But don't know how to fetch data from the database and show them on the graph.

With a single line graph I can connect to the database, but several don't know.

Can anyone help me? I really need help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look to this topic: [Multiple graphs in multiple figures using jFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20154153/1795530). In the answer is described how to work with `JFreeChart` and `SwingWorker` to make time consuming tasks (like database calls) in a background thread and update Swing components (in this case the chart) in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) where Swing components creation and update should take place.

Having said this you should do database calls within `doInBackground()` method publishing interim results through `publish()` method and adding those to the chart within `process()` method.

About database call you should have a look to [JDBC technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html). There are official trails here:

- [Lesson: JDBC Introduction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)
- [Lesson: JDBC
  Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/)

Depending on what database engine are you using there are some good tutorials too, just google for "jdbc + used DBMS" (e.g.: jdbc + mysql, jdbc + postgresql, jdbc + sqlite, etc.). Here is a really good one:

- [MySQL and Java JDBC - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: Also look at `JDBCXYDataset`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16959102/230513) and this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).